# LDAP - ldapwhoami returns "ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)"

Tags: ldap

I am new to working with LDAP, and my ultimate goal is to offer LDAP single sign-on in a web app. In order to achieve this, I'm trying to run `ldapwhoami`, but I'm running into issues. I am able to run other commands, like `ldapsearch` and `ldapadd`.

I'm running OpenLdap on Mac OS High Sierra.

My relevant `slapd.conf` looks like this:

```
access to *
  by self write
  by * read
  by anonymous auth

database    ldif

suffix          "dc=test,dc=com"
directory       openldap-data
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com"
## rootpw = secret
rootpw          {SSHA}fFjKcZb4cfOAcwSjJer8nCGOEVRUnwCC
```

I then added a user with `ldapadd -x -w secret -f shanson.ldif`, where `shanson.ldif` looks like:

```
dn: cn=shanson,dc=test,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
sn: Hanson
uid: shanson
cn: shanson
userPassword: secret
```

I am successfully able to search for and find this new user with `ldapsearch -x "(cn=shanson)"`.

Now, I am trying to verify the user's credentials using `ldapwhoami`, and I keep getting an error:

```
> ldapwhoami -x -D cn=shanson,dc=test,dc=com -w secret
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

The same operation with my root admin user succeeds:

```
> ldapwhoami -x -D cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com -w secret
dn:cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
```

I'm sure I'm just making a simple mistake or not understanding what I'm doing, but I don't really know where else to look right now for answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have had something to do with the plain text password I set up. I installed Jxplorer and manually updated my user's password and hashed it with MD5, and now the ldapwhoami command works. If I set the password as plain text in JXplorer, ldapwhoami still does not work. Beyond that, I'm not entirely sure what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my `dn` was wrong.

I did an `ldapsearch` with admin credentials to get the `dn: uid=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx`

Then I did an `ldapwhoami -x -D "uid=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx" -w secret` and it worked fine.